# PDO drivers no value in Windows while migrating PHP 7 from 5.6 in xampp

Tags: php, pdo, xampp, odbc, php-7

In PHP 5.6 all the drivers for PDO are working fine but while upgrading PHP version from 5.6.28 to 7.0.13 they are not working.

I have set extension=php_pdo.dll and extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll enabled in php.ini, but when I checked phpinfo(), the item PDO drivers is no value.

and also I can't find the mysql infos in phpinfo() but I have set extension=php_mysql.dll enabled.

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I figure out about your problem is, with the modifications you made, the PHP configuration does not change. Maybe the `php.ini` used is not the same? With the `phpinfo()` function, you should have the complete path of the `php.ini` file used. Try this piece of code in order to figure out this:

```
<?php

phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL);
```

The `Loaded Configuration File` is what you are looking for in order to do so.

Comment: I have not done any changes in php.ini file. As per your suggestion I have done changes and the output of Loaded Configuration File is **(none)**

Comment: That is interesting! When running PHP you may want to specify the php.ini file you edited with `-c <complete path>` option

Comment: I got it. in httpd-xampp.conf file, <IfModule php5_module> was needed to change with php7.